# How to see if a string contains all substrings from a list? [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the scenario:

I have a long list of time-stamped file names with characters before and after the time-stamp.

Something like this: `prefix_20160817_suffix`

What I want is a list (which will ultimately be a subset of the original list) that contains file names with specific prefixes, suffixes, and parts of the timestamp. These specific strings are already given in a list. Note: **this "contains" list might vary in size.**

For example: `['prefix1', '2016', 'suffix']` or `['201608', 'suffix']`

How can I easily get a list of file names that contain **every** element in the "contains" array?

Here's some pseudo code to demonstrate what I want:

```
for each fileName in the master list:
    if the fileName contains EVERY element in the "contains" array:
        add fileName to filtered list of filenames
```

Comment: `filtered_list = [fn for fn in master_list if all(item in fn for item in contains_list)]`

Comment: `all(element in fileName for element in contains)`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the downvote? What should I have done differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd compile the list into a [`fnmatch` pattern](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html):

```
import fnmatch

pattern = '*'.join(contains)
filetered_filenames = fnmatch.filter(master_list, pattern)
```

This basically concatenates all strings in `contains` into a glob pattern with `*` wildcards in between. This assumes the order of `contains` is significant. Given that you are looking for prefixes, suffixes and (parts of) dates in between, that's not that much of a stretch.

It is important to note that if you run this on an OS that has a case-insensitive filesystem, that `fnmatch` matching is also case-insensitive. This is usually exactly what you'd want in that case.

Comment: Thanks, this is an awesome answer. I can get my "contains" array as a string with asterisks VIA user input so it is even smoother this way.

Comment: @LukeH: if you are applying this to `os.lisdir()` output you may want to check out the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) too  and skip having to calling `os.listdir()` yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for something like that (using list comprehension and `all()`:

```
>>> files = ["prefix_20160817_suffix", "some_other_file_with_suffix"]
>>> contains = ['prefix', '2016', 'suffix']
>>> [ f for f in files if all(c in f for c in contains) ]
['prefix_20160817_suffix']
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
>>> cond1=['prefix1', '2016', 'suffix']
>>> cond2=['201608', 'suffix']
>>> fn="prefix_20160817_suffix"
```

You can test the existence of each substring in the list of conditions with `in` and (in the interim example) a list comprehension:

```
>>> [e in fn for e in cond1]
[False, True, True]
>>> [e in fn for e in cond2]
[True, True]
```

That can then be used in a single `all` statement to test all the substrings:

```
>>> all(e in fn for e in cond1)
False
>>> all(e in fn for e in cond2)
True
```

Then you can combine with `filter` (or use a list comprehension or a loop) to filter the list:

```
>>> fns=["prefix_20160817_suffix", "prefix1_20160817_suffix"]
>>> filter(lambda fn: all(e in fn for e in cond1), fns)
['prefix1_20160817_suffix']
>>> filter(lambda fn: all(e in fn for e in cond2), fns)
['prefix_20160817_suffix', 'prefix1_20160817_suffix']
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pseudocode was not far from a usable implementation as you see:

```
masterList=["prefix_20160817_suffix"]
containsArray=['prefix1', '2016', 'suffix']
filteredListOfFilenames=[]

for fileName in masterList:
    if all((element in fileName) for element in containsArray):
        filteredListOfFilenames.append(fileName)
```

I would suggest to have a deeper look into the really good [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) - it contains many useful things.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
filtered_list = []

for file_name in master_list:
    for element in contains_array:
        if element not in file_name:
            break
        filtered_list.append(file_name)
```